# After Add new Picker Code Is working on debugging mode but not working after release apk

Tags: react-native

After Adding Picker for Android that running in debugging mode but after release apk dont show picker value.
**note-apk is running on all devices only issue for new android devices their os is above than 9.+**

react-native picker

```
<Picker
selectedValue={this.state.loginAs}
style={styles. newpicker}
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
this.setState({loginAs: itemValue})
}>
```

picker value display in dropdown list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many I found the working solution for this. please try with the following solution and update on same.

The code was working fine for `debug` build not for `Release APK`.

My old code:-supporting for old device not for the `OS` version above `9.+`

```
<Picker
 selectedValue={this.state.loginAs}
 style={styles. newpicker}
 onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
 this.setState({loginAs: itemValue})
}>

<Picker.Item label="Select login As..." value="Select login As..." color='#9EA0A4'/>
{this.state.loginData.map((item, index) => {
return (
<Picker.Item label={item.role} value={item.role} key={index}/>)
})}
</Picker>
```

> Working Solution

Added Following Line into the `AndroidManifest.xml` because the reason is I was using `http` in `webAPI` if you are using `http url` add following line else no need .

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```